# R Markdown - Hyperlink outside Rmd file

Tags: r, hyperlink, markdown, r-markdown

I am wondering how we can define a hyperlink for R markdown outside Rmd file. Defining a hyperlink inside Rmd file is as easy as typing [hyperlink lable](actual link); but, if on the Rmd file, I am calling some other r-file (e.g., a function) that generates an address to a file, is there a way to transfer this information back to Rmd file to generate a hyperlink there?

Please see example below for more clarification:

Inside Rmd file:

```
myFun( with some input)
```

Inside myFun:

```
myFun <- function( with some input)
some calculations...
return("[click here](C:/myFile.docx)")
```

The output on the generated html page is:

[1] "[click here] (C:/myFile.docx)"

Which is not a hyperlink!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, assuming the output of 'myFun' function is the hyperlink string, here is what worked best for me:

Inside myFun:

```
myFun <- function()
...some calculations to generate a csv file...
return("C:/myFile.csv")
```

Inside Rmd file:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
myHyperlink <- myFun()
hyperlink_exists = !is.null(myHyperlink)
```

```{r, eval=hyperlink_exists, results="asis", echo=FALSE}
cat(paste0("The file is saved ","[", "Here", "](", myHyperlink, ")","\n"))
```
````

Answer (score 2):

To define the links outside the `rmd` file you can use a [parameterized report](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports). This allows you to pass values into the `rmarkdown` document when you compile it. To do this, first create an `rmarkdown` document that includes the desired parameters, which are declared in the `yaml` header and then used later in the report. Then, in a separate R script, run the `render` command (from the `rmarkdown` package) and pass the desired parameter values.

Here's an example that uses `cat` or `paste` to generate the links. For comparison, I've also added a second set of parameters that add different links using the methods in @JohnCoene's answer. I've saved the `rmarkdown` document as `"test.rmd"`, which is how the document is identified in the `render` command.

#### `rmarkdown` document

````
---
output: html_document
params:
  text1: "add text"
  link1: "add URL"
  text2: "add text"
  link2: "add URL" 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
# Function to add link 
myFun <- function(text, link, inline=TRUE) {
  if(inline) {
    paste("[", text, "](", link, ")", sep="")
  } else {
    cat("[", text, "](", link, ")", sep="")
  }
}
```

Blah, blah, blah, more text. And here's the link: 

```{r, results="asis"}
myFun(params$text1, params$link1, inline=FALSE)
```

Blah, blah, blah, more text. And here's a way to `r myFun(params$text1, params$link1)`.

Or, using the examples from `@JohnCoene's` answer:

With an HTML tag:

```{r, results="asis"}
tg <- function (link, text){
  paste0("<a href='", link, "'>", text, "</a>")
}

tg(params$link2, params$text2)
```

With `htmltools`:

```{r}
# install.packages("htmltools")
library(htmltools)

tags$a(
  href = params$link2,
  params$text2
)
```
````

#### Separate R script to render the `rmarkdown` document

```
library(rmarkdown)

render(input="test.rmd", 
       params=list(text1="link to Stackoverflow", 
                   link1="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745926/r-markdown-hyperlink-outside-rmd-file",
                   text2="link to google",
                   link2="https://google.com"))
```

---

Here's what the output html document looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions, return an html tag or use the htmltools package.

### HTML tag

````
```{r, results="asis"}
tg <- function (link, text){
  paste0("<a href='", link"'>", text, "</a>")
}

tg("http://google.com", "link to Google")
```
````

### htmltools

Definitely *recommend* this way over the other.

````
```{r}
# install.packages("htmltools")
library(htmltools)

tags$a(
  href = "https://google.com",
  "Link to Google"
)
```
````